# Login to MigrosoftGraph from winform application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to connect from a .NET application to MicrosoftGraph, but the program gets stuck in one place when reading data.
The login will probably work well, because it will be returned to me by AccessToken, but then it will not happen when the data is retrieved.

```
    Task<User> tu = graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    tu.Wait();      //it will stop me here
```

I have created an application in Microsoft Graph, application rights set. But is there something missing from me ???

```
    var tenantId = "__my tenant__";
    var appId = "__my app id__";
    var clientSecret = "__my secret__";

    //var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var scopes = new string[] { "api://89__my id__1/.default" };

    // Initialize the auth provider with values from appsettings.json
    var authProvider = new DeviceCodeAuthProvider(tenantId, appId, clientSecret, scopes);

    // Request a token to sign in the user
    var accessToken = authProvider.GetAccessToken().Result;

    // Initialize Graph client
    GraphHelper.Initialize(authProvider);

    // Get signed in user
    var user = GraphHelper.GetMeAsync();        //it gets stuck inside the method
    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {user.DisplayName}!\n");
```

```
    public class DeviceCodeAuthProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApplication;
        private string[] _scopes;
        private IAccount _userAccount;

        public DeviceCodeAuthProvider(string tenantId, string appId, string clientSecret, string[] scopes)
        {
            _scopes = scopes;
            
            _confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(appId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            // If there is no saved user account, the user must sign-in
            if (_userAccount == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var task = _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                    task.Wait();
                    var result = task.Result;

                    _userAccount = result.Account;
                    return result.AccessToken;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error getting access token: {exception.Message}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await _confidentialClientApplication
                    .AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, _userAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                return result.AccessToken;
            }
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetAccessToken());
        }
    }

    public class GraphHelper
    {
        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient;

        public static void Initialize(IAuthenticationProvider authProvider)
        {
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        }

        public static User GetMeAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // GET /me
                Task<User> tu = graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
                tu.Wait();

                User u = tu.Result;
                return u;
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting signed-in user: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting signed-in user: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your using Application permission the /me endpoint is supported

> Calling the /me endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a delegated permission. Application permissions are not supported when using the /me endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

So just include the user you what to access eg

```
Task<User> tu = graphClient.Users["user@domain.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work. We think that we have everything set up correctly for the application account in Microsoft Azure but we cannot get over the point when the app is stuck in the attempt to read the data. We are looking for someone to help us go over this issue. Can we make a short telco for this? We are ready to reimburse your time spent on helping us to resolve the issue.

Comment: No thank you. I downloaded another solution for communicating with MSGraph.